# How do I get current url of same page?

Tags: java, selenium

```html
 <a href="!#" data-toggle="dropdown">Shuttle 
 <span class="caret"></span></a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="/client1/shuttle/">Generate Trips </a>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </li>
```

When I run this code in chrome browser I am getting proper current url of same page but when I run this same code in chrome headless browser, it's going to logout the screen.I also gave the page load timeout but I am unable to fetch the current url of same page.

For headeless I am giving,

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.setHeadless(true);
 options.addArguments("--window-size=1440x900");
 driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

// Load the properties File
 props = new Properties();
 props.load(data.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties"));
 // Get Url
     driver.get(props.getProperty("url"));
```

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpjFU.png) I want Generatetrips tab link

```
     WebElement first = 
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(props.getProperty("tabfirst")));
                // click trip generate
                WebElement second = 
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(props.getProperty("tabsecond")));

    Actions a = new Actions(driver);
    a.moveToElement(first).moveToElement(second).click().build().perform();

    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());


    tabfirst=//a[contains(text(),'Shuttle')]  
    tabsecond=//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']/li[3]/a[contains(text(),'Generate Trips')]
```

Comment: What is the url you are loading?

Comment: First i am loading home screen url. Then i am clicking to another url

Comment: Is it your website? Are you trying to scrape from another website? Sometimes there are bot defense mechanism that blocks headless browsers. Try to override the user agent https://intoli.com/blog/making-chrome-headless-undetectable/

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: When I am clicking to the generate tab, my current screen is being logged out automatically. But I want generate tab url link.

Comment: Share your HTML for that tabs.

Comment: Try if you can get the href/src under that `generate tab`?